# Error Images Size When Refresh A Page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a brand logo on Bootstrap Nav.

```
<a href="http://localhost/SGW" class="logo hero_logo">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://localhost/SGW/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/unnamed.png" alt="Sai Gon Works">
</a>
```

Original size of images is 1909 x 406. And I have a style for

```
.hero_logo {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 300px;
}
```

But when i refresh page, my logo is expand until my page load done. You can see this issue in my video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQAZmyWRfbo&feature=youtu.be

How to fix it?

Comment: where is the link to the css file? is it on the top of the page or bottom? if it is not it should be on the top inside the head tag

Comment: Link to my css file I put in head tag. But I don't think it make my issue, because all my style in css are works.

Answer (score 1):

Add your `hero_logo` class to `<img>` tag, not `<a>` and it should work. Or add `width=300` to `<img>` tag.

Comment: It just expand a little bit. But, result is better than before. :). Thanks